# passing a variable to a ajax request Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, request

I am trying to pass a variable to an ajax request via jquery. I have a triggered event that defines the variable. I want to do this so that I can have one ajax request handle multiple urls. I have alerted the url and it come back fine, but when I plug it into the URL slot of a $.ajax request my targeted content does not load. Here is my code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('a').live('click', function(){
      var link = $(this).attr("href");
       $.ajax({
           url: link,
           success: function(html){
                $('#load').html(html)
           }
      });
   });

});
```

this has been a real headache and I feel I am just misusing something. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a shortcut for this using [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) :)

```
$('a').live('click', function(){
  $('#load').load($(this).attr("href"));
});
```

Be aware of the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) that Justin is alluding to as well, requests to different domains are prohibited for security reasons.

Comment: thanks for the shortcut sadly the the content still does not show. The 



















thanks i have tried the load method not in this format (which is cleaner :])but it still does not work.

Comment: @user304735 - Can you host some sample HTML this is being run on?

Answer (score 1):

What URL are you passing in? If it is for a different domain the AJAX call will not be executed.

Comment: no its a path in the same server. Im passing through simple things like link1.html, link2.hmtl thanks